# HTML input range showing intervals

Tags: html, input, range, intervals

Is it possible to add the intervals on to a HTML input range. Essentially so that the user can easily just click the bar at the given intervals. I know there are some customs sliders that use JS and CSS but I just want the standard bar with some vertical lines on really.

**EDIT**
Sorry I should have been more clear:
What I'm looking for is entirely visual, I'll post my code below but I have implemented the step attribute what I want is a visual representation on the bar showing the user that there are 5 possible steps/intervals on the bar and that is what is available to them.

```
    <input id="slider" max="5" min="1" step="1" style="width:90%; height:30%; type="range" value="5">
```

Answer (score 5):

You mean like this (see code below)? You need to add the `step="X"` variable to your range slider.

What's **step**?

> Works with the `min` and `max` attributes to limit the increments at which
>   a numeric or date-time value can be set. It can be the string any or a
>   positive floating point number. If this attribute is not set to any,
>   the control accepts only values at multiples of the step value greater
>   than the minimum.

Read more about it at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

```html
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="1" max="11" step="2" />
```

Comment: The problem with that particular answer is that according to the comments this does not work on Mac OS and as I'm currently on a Mac this is problematic ha

Answer (score 0):

Add `step` attribute to the input field.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice example, originally posted on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#adding_tick_marks):

```html
<label for="temp">Choose a comfortable temperature:</label><br />
<input type="range" id="temp" name="temp" list="markers" />

<datalist id="markers">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="25"></option>
  <option value="50"></option>
  <option value="75"></option>
  <option value="100"></option>
</datalist>
```